# Jekyll Liquid Syntax errors

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to add a theme to my Github Pages Jekyll blog and am trying to serve it up locally. First, I am not sure how to instal the theme as it does not depend on Jekyll-bootstrap. So far I've forked the repository on Github, renamed it, cloned it and now I am trying to see what it looks like before deploying it.

I navigate to my Github pages repo locally and type in

```
jekyll build serve
```

And it throws this error:

```
Liquid Exception: Included file '_includes/post-grid.html' not found in skinny-bones-jekyll/index.md
```

I do not know what this means. Can someone please explain what is happening? I am also going to go to the guy's repository on GitHub.

Thank you.

Comment: It means that template doesn't exist. You should put that template there or change your post to not look for that template

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Still messing around with it.